# How does one create a cluster from different servers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have servers A, B & C with 8 cores each. Right now, I'm running jobs in parallel on a single server with 8 workers. Is there any way I can harness the power of all three for a single job? The servers are all inter-accessible via ssh (all three exist behind a gateway, so no password required either)

Comment: Parallelising within one job sounds very tricky indeed, and I doubt there's any support for that in Matlab.  It would also give you sub-linear performance increases, even if it were possible.  Parallelising multiple jobs (as you're doing now) is much easier, and much more efficient.  Why would you want to change that?

Comment: you would have to be working on a task that could naturally be split into many parts with few inter-dependencies. For example a huge for loop whore body depends only on loop counter. Do you have such a situation?

Comment: Oli, I think you misunderstood me... I'm just trying to run the same job that I run now (8 workers on one machine) on 24 workers across 3 machines.

David, I'm already running it in parallel, so the task can be split into parts independent of iteration loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're currently using Parallel Computing Toolbox. To use multiple servers together, you need the following things:

1. [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/) licences for the MATLAB workers running on the machines.
2. Some sort of scheduler to schedule the jobs across the machines. MDCS comes with a basic scheduler, call the "Jobmanager". There are also various freely available schedulers for Linux systems such as [Torque](http://www.clusterresources.com/products/torque-resource-manager.php).

The installation instructions for MDCS are quite detailed and will lead you through all the stages you need to complete to get parallel jobs running.